# Assemble transitive closure of a main file in scala sbt project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, executable-jar, sbt-assembly

I'm working on a scala sbt project, and I am at a point where I want to assemble the whole thing to share a .jar-file with others, so that they can use it on their side. For my local testing, I'm doing so using the sbt-assembly plugin, that works nicely.

When sharing, I would though prefer to only share the parts that are important for the other party (the project has huge components that irrelevant at the current point, and I'd prefer not to share these for various reasons). Concretely, they will be executing one particular main file, so it would be enough to pack everything that this file depends on.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'd also be interested in doing this on the code level (i.e., create a copy of the project that only contains dependencies of that main file), but also while assembling or even modifying the jar file after assembly is okay. I did not find the tools to achieve any of these.

As I said, I'm dealing with a scala sbt project, and I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA; I'd also be happy with an IDE tool that does the job.

Comment: Why not just split the project into multiple projects or multiple modules of the same project?

Comment: The project contains several algorithms for several related problems that share a common base, and my goal is to provide a jar that allows executing one algorithm for one problem. I don't think having separate modules or even projects is the way I would want to go here.

Comment: Separate modules sound exactly what you would want to do. You will have a `core` module that will contain the logic that is shared across each algorithm. And then a module for each algorithm _(or set of related algorithms)_ which will depend on `core` - That way you can create an assembly jar for each sub-module that is not `core` and distribute them as you please.